# Does Apple offer fanless macs or imacs?

Tags: mac, imac

Does Apple offer fanless desktop machines in its current lineup? I could not find any information searching for this.

Answer (score 3):

No, all current Macs have fans. At low load, most Mac fans are very quiet though.

Comment: NOOOOO, WHY NOT?

Comment: Because most people probably wouldn't want their CPU to melt through their legs.

Comment: @user782220 If you really need something fanless, pick up an iPad or iPod touch